# Combine jQuery .addClass() on button click only to element that button is in

Tags: jquery, button, merge, addclass

I am trying to combine multiple click functions with toggle class into one that will affect multiple elements separately. As seen on image i want to change css of element on click only for one which is inside same parent element as button ignoring any other elements with same class.

HTML:

```
<div style="display: inline-block">    
    <section class="container2">
       1
    </section>
    <section>
        <p><button id="button">change</button></p>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
    background: red !important;
}
.container2 {
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var removeClass = true;

$("#button").click(function () {
    $('.container2').toggleClass('background');
    removeClass = false;
});

$(".container2").click(function() {
    removeClass = false;
});

$("html").click(function () {
    if (removeClass) {
        $(".container2").removeClass('background');
    }
    removeClass = true;
});

http://jsfiddle.net/dkhhecf2/1/
```

I know i can write something like this

> $("#one, #two, #three").click...

But is there any other way?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJhKu.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="inline actionset">
   <div>1</div>
    <button>change</button>
</div>
<div class="inline actionset">
    <div>2</div>
    <button>change</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inline {
    display:inline-block;
}
.highlight {
    background: red !important;
}
.actionset > div {
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
}
```

JS

```
$('.actionset button').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var el = $this.prev();
    el.toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkhhecf2/2/

1. An ID can only be used once per page
2. Your markup needed some help to clean it up

As for the JS, you have a reference to the element being clicked $(this). Using this you can traverse the DOM using jQuery to select the element you want to affect. I used [prev();](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, id has to be unique. So, you can NOT have the same id for different element. 
And, in order to fire the function to different elements, it is easy that elements have different id.

Hence,

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#1").toggleClass("background");

});


$("#button2").click(function(){
    $("#2").toggleClass("background");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkhhecf2/3/